# Fotos en variaciones de precio | Woocomerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Este es mi primer post, ya que soy nuevo en este tipo de cosas. En la web de mi empresa trabajamos con woocomerce, nuestros productos tienen variaciones de y una de ellas es el color del producto, esta variación solo tiene la foto con el color del producto porque el precio está en otras variaciones que tienen como el tipo de impresión o cantidades. De tal manera que queda algo como la imagen adjunta.

Las primeras variaciones están hechas solo de la imagen sin precios y las últimas son una variación con cantidad y tipo de impresión, ¿cómo puedo mostrar la imagen de la variación pero el precio de la otra variación?

[image: Foto]

Answer (score 0):

te adjunto dirección de un video que me ha ayudado con eso

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBkjqvEFBrY

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/406055)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).